# Developing an online platform for generating text logos

Tags: web-development, website-design, responsive-webdesign

I'm trying to develop a online platform which will automatically generates text logos when the text inputs by user. I searched many ways to find some resources to starting my task. but couldn't found anything yet. Still I have no idea how to start this project, where to start and which programming language is suitable.

Comment: This site is for help with [operating and managing websites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rather than developing them.